# How to query entries with EntityContainer Name in OData V3?

Tags: odata

Is there anyone knows how to query entries with EntityContainer Name in OData V3?
According http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/ , I should have being able to achieve it with url:
http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/DemoService.Persons

So, is there anyone can tell me what is wrong with my request?
Thanks in advance